# How to handle class 'bytes' when reading data from Firebird using Python

Tags: python, sql, firebird

This snippet of code is responsible for dumping the data in a fdb file into a json file

```
import fdb
import json
import sys
import decimal
import datetime


def js(val):
    if type(val) == int:
        return val
    if type(val) == str:
        return val
    if val is None:
        return val
    if type(val) == decimal.Decimal:
        return str(val)
    if type(val) == datetime.datetime:
        return val.isoformat()
    # else:
    #     return str(val)
    raise Exception(type(val))


con = fdb.connect(dsn='202204.fdb', user='sysdba', password='masterkey')

cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute(
    "SELECT a.RDB$RELATION_NAME FROM RDB$RELATIONS a WHERE RDB$SYSTEM_FLAG=0")


tables = [row[0].strip() for row in cur.fetchall()]

db = {}

for table in tables:
    db[table] = {}
    cur.execute(
        f"select rdb$field_name from rdb$relation_fields where rdb$relation_name='{table}' order by rdb$field_position")

    db[table]['cols'] = [head[0].strip() for head in cur.fetchall()]

    cur.execute(f"select * from \"{table}\"")

    db[table]['rows'] = [[js(field) for field in row]
                         for row in cur.fetchall()]

with open('202204.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(db, f, indent=4)


cur.close()
```

js raises the Exception: <class 'bytes'> (which is intentional) as I don't know how to handle bytes

I've attempted decoding with utf-8 to be greeted with this
`UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode bytes in position 0-1: invalid continuation byte`

and this with latin-1 `TypeError: decoding to str: need a bytes-like object, BlobReader found`

just returning the value as is returns me this error `TypeError: Object of type bytes is not JSON serializable`

and finally, returning the val as a string returns me one of 2 things
100kb strings that look like this
`"b'\\xec\\xbauP\\\\m\\xb7\\'\\xdah\\x80\\xe0\\xae\\xa1qw\\x08\\x16\\xdc]\\x1bww\\x87\\x0eN\\x90\\xe0.\\x01\\x12\\xdc\\xdd!\\xb8\\x93`

or

`"<fdb.fbcore.BlobReader object at 0x000001DCD636AD30>"`

would appreciate any pointers on how to move forward!

Comment: This should help: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.decode

Comment: mentioned my attempts in decoding haven't worked and their resulting errors

Comment: I would suggest to check [working with BLObs](https://fdb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage-guide.html#working-with-blobs). What you fetch is `BloBReader` object

Comment: If something is binary data, you can't just convert to UTF-8 and expect it to work. It is binary data, and that is not necessarily text (and if it is text, you need to know the appropriate encoding to apply). Depending on your use case, you might need `base64.b64encode` instead (but without context about the actual column data, that is just a wild ass guess).

Comment: The suggestion to use base64 is just if it is actually binary data and you need to put it in that JSON you seem to want to create based on your earlier questions.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel The problem is I also have no idea what is inside these files so I've also been, as you put it, "wild ass guessing". Base64 decoding hasn't gotten me the results I need :/

Comment: I said base64 **encoding** not decoding, so you can put the binary data in your JSON. But otherwise, you really need to talk to someone who knows this specific database and/or investigate how to handle it by looking at the data with a query tool like FlameRobin or DBeaver.

Comment: Followed your suggestion and downloaded DBeaver DATA column has a type of BLOB SUB_TYPE-16. clicking on it gets me this error
```SQL Error [337248295] [0F001]: Blob is invalid. Blob was freed, or closed by transaction end. [SQLState:0F001, ISC error code:337248295]```
and exporting to csv has it become a really long string that looks something like this
`7Lp1UFxttyfaaIDgrqFxdwgW3F0bd3eHDk6Q4C4BEtzdIbiT4O40BA8e3GE67znf3DPfqVs1U/PXrbrPqv7tp9devlY9e3dVI72BAaAD/rWGYQEAlL8L5i9IWpq6AeUtnZxsrSzdmFFQNG1MneyB3s6eQCtnN6CZs7O9rZ` this is just an excerpt

Comment: With DBeaver you'll need to disable auto-commit if you get the content of the blobs using the button looking like a T to the right of "Rollback" in the menubar). The lifetime of a blob handle is tied to the transaction, and the way the query is executed will end the transaction once all rows have been fetched.

Comment: In any case, as far as I can tell the example string you provide is purely binary data, but I'm not sure what kind of file type it is. As what a BLOB SUB_TYPE -16 really is, that is application specific. Maybe it is defined in the RDB$TYPES table (`select * from RDB$TYPES where RDB$TYPE = -16 and RDB$FIELD_NAME  = 'RDB$FIELD_SUB_TYPE'`), but not all application developers make the effort to name their custom sub-types that way.

Comment: the line of SQL on the field did not return any useful data, but thanks for the tip on DBeaver. It's still however showing as a 32418x5 hex matrix which I'm not sure how to decode into real data.